# Adverb for the verb spend

Tags: verbs, adverbs

I read in a piece of news . " the amount of time that young people spend inactive." Inactive is an adjective . I consider it should be inactively . Is it right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["buy... clever" & "buy... miserable" {You can't buy your kids clever}](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150957/buy-clever-buy-miserable). See also [Is this ... an adjective phrase?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91077/is-this-an-objective-complement-or-adjective-phrase/91152#91152), where 'He caught me _off guard_' is analysed as a depictive construction ('off guard' modifying 'me', the object). Here, it's subject-orientated.

Answer (score 2):

No, "inactively" doesn't work here. This is what the relative clause says:

> Young people spend X amount of time inactive.

Which could be read along these lines:

> Young people are inactive for X hours a day on average.

The adjective "inactive" says something about the subject "young people".

Comment: Yes. But one would say "He spent the afternoon inactively" since "inactive(ly)" is describing neither "the afternoon", nor "he". It is describing the way it was spent.

Comment: That's right of course, but I'd think that "inactively" probably sits better modifying "one-time" events, as in your example, rather than serial occurrences as in the OP. I'd guess that there is also a slight difference in meaning between the adjective and the adverb. "Inactive" in the context of the noun phrase from the OP says "not engaging in physical activity" while your example rather suggests "I was being idle", "inactively" saying like "I wasn't doing anything particularly important."

Comment: A good comparison is "time that young people spend asleep". It's obvious here that "asleep" is an adjective.

Comment: A **relative clause** would be understood as _Young people spend X amount of time **that is inactive**._ But that's not what's happening here.

Comment: "Inactive" cannot be understood that way  in the noun phrase from the OP.  The nominal "amount of time" is the head of the phrase which is modified by the relative clause "that young people spend inactive". In no way can "inactive" be understood as modifying "time". It is predicated of "young people", it is them that it modifies, not the verb or "time". If you used the adjective suggested by Stuart F above, your analysis would lead to: "Young people spend X amount of time that is asleep". This obviously isn't a plausible reading.

Comment: Sorry, I though *you* were trying to call *inactive* a (reduced) relative clause (which it is not). I now see that you were referring to the original construction's relative clause: *that young people spend inactive*.

Answer (score 2):

No. The adjective is correct.

> "the amount of time that young people spend inactive."

means "the amount of time that young people spend **as a result of being** inactive."

This use of adjectives has two categories:

Resultative: https://www.usingenglish.com/glossary/resultative-adjective.html

I shot him dead = I shot him [and, as a result, he was] dead.

He beat the metal flat = He beat the metal [and, as a result, it was] flat.

Descriptive:

She arrived at the meeting drunk = She arrived at the meeting [and she was] drunk.

But

She arrived at the meeting drunkly = She arrived at the meeting [as if she were] drunk. Here she might not have been drunk - she might have been ill or injured.

There is an interesting and readable paper on this at http://wvw.broccias.net/research/SLE2001.pdf 
entitled "Unsubcategorized objects in English resultative constructions" by Cristiano Broccias (Università di Pavia)

Comment: _Young people spend time **as a result of** being inactive*_ is not correct. If it were, _She arrived **as a result of** being drunk_ would be analogous.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat  I agree with you on this one. The OP phrase doesn't mean "the amount of time that young people spend as a result of being inactive". The adjective "inactive" is used descriptively in this phrase - ascribes a property to the subject "young people". So, it cannot be understood as modifying the situation of spending time. "Inactive" cannot be understood as a resulting state of the subject either. Not only in this sentence but in no other transitive clause can the resulting state expressed by the adjective be linked to the subject.

Comment: So, we can say : He drove her home drunk. , meaning that he was driving drunk, but we cannot read "drunk" in "He got her drunk" as referring to his drunkenness - it has to be "her" who ended up drunk. Resultatives in transitive clauses are always understood as predicated of the object, not the subject of the sentence. Or in the example with the adjective "inactive" -  He made the account inactive. - "inactive" can only be understood as saying something about the account, not about him. It indicates the resulting state that the account is brought to.

Comment: @RejlanGivens: Summary: _He drove the car drunk_ (depictive, subject oriented, he = drunk). _He drank the beer warm_ (depictive, object oriented, beer = warm). _He drove me crazy_ (resultative, object oriented, me = crazy via the verb action).

Comment: Sounds good to me Tinfoil Hat. In CGEL they label this function "predicative adjunct" . In literature I've also come across terms "secondary predication" and "small clause" for this same function. The other two terms stress the fact that this element is understood  as predicate in the linking construction. We can often clearly see two predications, as in this example with drinking : He drove the car. He was drunk.